# Totally Ordered Multicast with Lamport Clocks without FIFO

Tags: distributed, distributed-system

Typically, I learned in lecture that Totally Ordered multicast with Lamport clocks can be achieved under ***assumption that network is reliable and FIFO*** multicast order.
This requires total message of **N (initial broadcast) + N^2 (ACKs)**

However, one of the question I had was optimize the above algorithm so that it has same total ordering but **incur significant fewer total messages**.  Also, it should also work under reliable network, **but without FIFO**.

Can we actually achieve optimized algorithm (reduce number of messages) without FIFO guarantee in network?